# iPod touch can't get IP address from Airport Express

Tags: network, wifi, ipod-touch, airport

I've got the following setup:

- DSL modem connected via Ethernet to an Airport Express
- A second Airport Express extending the first
- Both Airports Express are the current model, running version 7.6.4 of their software.

Between the two I have nine working wireless client devices, mostly Macs and iOS devices.

However my 5th-gen iPod touch can't get an IP address. It *connects* to the wireless network, but keeps a self-assigned IP address. I can see this address both on the iPod touch and in Airport Utility (on a Mac). So I know it's connecting, but for some reason it can't get an address.

I've tried:

- Rebooting the iPod touch
- Resetting network settings on the iPod touch
- Resetting *all* settings on the iPod touch
- Upgrading the iPod touch from iOS 8.0.2 to iOS 8.1

No change. I could do a full wipe/restore on the iPod touch, but with everything above already failing, I'm skeptical it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens the solution was just to **reboot all the things**. In this case it eventually turned out that the DSL modem (which is also the router) was the culprit.